# Multiple ArrayAdapter, single array

Tags: android, synchronization, arraylist, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I have an ArrayList containing data for displaying. The content changes asynchronously.
I want to display the data in two Activities, both are using an ArrayAdapter (not the same class).

The problem is that ArrayAdapter provides synchronized access and notifications through add, insert and remove. So synchronized access is only possible through one and not two adapers.

The ArrayAdapter itself is not resusable since diffent views are used.

So the question is: what is the recommended architecture for having one ArrayList with multiple ArrayAdapter's?

**Update**
I would like to clarify. At the moment I have only one ArrayAdapter.

- the data is stored in an ArrayList
- a service is updating the data in the background via the ArrayAdapter
- both Activity and service are accessing the ArrayList via the ArrayAdapter (multithreading synchronisation issues), but this is no issue because ArrayAdapter does the locking

Now I have another activity which should also display the same ArrayList and I don't know what to do. Clearly I need another ArrayAdapter, because the second activity has another layout. This means that two activities and a service are accessing the same ArrayList. The synchronisation of the ArrayAdapter is not sufficient any more, because the locking is in the ArrayAdapter, which means if service and activity 1 are using ArrayAdapter 1, ArrayAdapter 2 will still access and modify the ArrayList.

Answer (score 3):

> The content changes asynchronously.

I'm not sure I understand how you use the ArrayList between the two activities. (static field?)

> The problem is that ArrayAdapter takes ownership for the array (it
>   duplicates it).

I don't believe it duplicates it. It stores a reference to it. (correct me if I am wrong)

> When Activity2 is activated and creates ArrayAdapter2, the ArrayList
>   still belongs to ArrayAdapter1.

Both ArrayAdapters should have a reference to the same ArrayList at this point. This means that a change in the ArrayList would be reflected in both adapters.

Comment: Could you give a proof link to android code (Array Adapter) ,I could be wrong but your answer may be incorrect

Comment: Line 312 - https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#L308

Comment: 1) The ArrayList is a static field somewhere. 2) you are right. 3) yes, but synchronized access and notification is only possible through one adapter

Answer (score 0):

Use one global array adapter for two activities and observe you async data.

Comment: But an array adapter is view specific. Could you be more specific or point me to an example?

Comment: If you look into github code  https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java you can see that only methods add(),insert() and etc call notifyDataSetChanged() and fill mObjects.So when you have some async changes in your ArrayList, the second(another) ArrayAdapter doest know about it

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem. After changes in arrayList through one adapter, call [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)() for the other one. That is all you need, IMHO. At least, it is enough for my ArrayList that is also in different Activity with its adapter. And I change it "by hand" and notify the adapter later, too.

The serious problem will be if you'll want to have one **ListView** with two adapters. But that is  a senselees task, I think.

**Updating the answer up to the updated question:**

So, the problem is not in the two activities that are using the same arraylist by different ArrayAdapters, but in three components using possibly two different arrayadapters. But if you are using the second adapter only for displaying of the same list, as you are writing here, you needn't any additional synchronization at all. Simply call adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged() after every significant change.

The problem could arise only if you are doing simultaneous changes through two different adapters. Each wouldn't be notified in time on the changes made by the other one. As for synchronization between Activities in the case of probable simultaneous writing, you can reach it by notifying after every change focus from one Activity to another.

But writing synchronization between service+adapter1 and activity+adapter2 could be reached only if you'll find youself some important points in your code where the mutual notifications and locking/unlocking should be made.

Comment: But when you do so, locking doesn't work. Both ArrayAdapter use different locks which means that the access to the ArrayList is not synchronized. That is what is bothering me.

Comment: Ah! You want to guarantee, that adapter 2  won't refresh while you are working with adapter 1?

Comment: IMHO, adapter refreshes itself only when a ListView refreshes itself (i.e. at redraw). Or by notifyDataSetChanged.